# Differences between Hunter: the Reckoning and Hunter: the Vigil?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, world-of-darkness, hunter-the-vigil

I don't understand the differences between the oWoD Hunter and nWoD Hunter. Most of the games I could see a fairly clear difference in mechanics and theme between them.

I have not been able to find much difference between Hunter: the Reckoning and Hunter: the Vigil. What are the key differences in mechanics and theme?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Imbued (the protagonists of **Hunter: the Reckoning**) are universally empowered by an otherworldly source to accomplish literally miraculous deeds. They have the ability to pierce supernatural protections and disguises and hear what could be described as the Voice of God guiding them. The themes of HtR are about heroism, fanaticism, truth, and faith, as well as being explicitly a "new" faction in the classic World of Darkness who have arrived at the cusp of the End of Days. The Imbued divide themselves by [Creed](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Creed), representative of their philosophical approach to how to treat monsters: Avengers, Martyrs, Defenders, Innocents, Judges, Redeemers, Visionaries, Hermits, and so on.

Hunters in **Hunter: the Vigil** may have supernatural power, and may have issues of heroism and faith, but they have no particular universal endorsement or capability. Their stories are about desperate last stands and the desire to defeat, destroy or exploit monsters. Vigil hunters divide themselves into Compacts and Conspiracies, which are as much social groupings as power sources.

Comment: Not all Hunters from HtV have supernatural power. In fact, they are broken down into three tiers: Cells (small groups of lone hunters), Compacts (larger groups that trade information and assistance) and Conspiracies (huge undercover groups with a global reach). Only members of Conspiracies can have Endowments, a kind of supernatural benefit which is different for each Conspiracy.

Comment: It's worth asking, but does H:tR have all of the factions? there are numerous factions, including more added in the supplements to H:tV

Comment: @arthexis Indeed. That's why my answer says "may," rather than "do," when it comes to Vigil Hunters.

Comment: @xenoterracide The HtR hunters don't have any of the Vigil factions; they have Creeds, which are splats based on their approach to their supernatural hunt. I'll add more about that.

Comment: I would also add that they just not simply "have" supernatural power, but rather that their powers have been cobbled / granted / stolen from the very supernaturals they hunt and in fact the theme of "becoming a monster to hunt monsters" comes up a lot. HtV hunters also pursue Slashers, who are not exactly supernatural beings, but kind of the serial killers and human-monsters of fiction (think Hannibal Lecter or Jigsaw).